# Объясните пожалуйста алгоритм нахождения наименьшего общего кратного

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм

Есть решение задачи по нахождения наименьшего общего кратного для массива чисел arr:

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
var range = [];
for (var i = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]); i >= Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]); i--) {
range.push(i);
}

var lcm = range[0];
for (i = 1; i < range.length; i++) {
var GCD = gcd(lcm, range[i]);
lcm = (lcm * range[i]) / GCD;
}
return lcm;

function gcd(x, y) {
if (y === 0)
    return x;
else
    return gcd(y, x%y);
}
```

Объясните пожалуйста по шагам что к чему?

Comment: Мы Вам что, дебаггер?

Comment: Но так и быть. Объясняю. В приведенном коде не хватает фигурной скобки.

Comment: @Igor Ну и кто же теперь поверит, что Вы не дебаггер?

Comment: Прошу прощения, упустил скобку.

Answer (score 1):

Кто Вам дал этот код? Не верьте больше этому человеку. Например, я знаю, что наименьшее общее кратное для трех чисел `6, 8 и 10` это `120`. А теперь нажмите на кнопку "Выполнить код".

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  var range = [];
  for (var i = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]); i >= Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]); i--) {
    range.push(i);
  }

  var lcm = range[0];
  for (i = 1; i < range.length; i++) {
    var GCD = gcd(lcm, range[i]);
    lcm = (lcm * range[i]) / GCD;
  }
  return lcm;

  function gcd(x, y) {
    if (y === 0)
      return x;
    else
      return gcd(y, x % y);
  }
}

console.log(smallestCommons([6, 8, 10]));
```

Comment: Этот код дал какой-то добрый человек. Решение вязто отсюда https://guide.freecodecamp.org/certifications/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/smallest-common-multiple/. Задача состоит в том, чтобы найти НОК для всего массива чисел, т.е. для простых чисел в промежутке между [a, b]